# How to get current_[entity] from registry?

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, registry

I am creating a custom module collection which has content as product grid serialization.
I have referred article [How to create the Product Grid Serializer Block In Custom module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13305/how-to-create-the-product-grid-serializer-block-in-custom-module).

I use `Mage::registry('current_[entity]')->getId();` to get the id. In my case I have used 
`Mage::registry('current_collections')->getId();` But i am getting error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function `getId()` on a non-object in ..`Tab/Product.php` file.

How can I get current collections id from registry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php

```
/**
 * Initialize order model instance
 *
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order || false
 */
protected function _initOrder()
{
    ....

    Mage::register('sales_order', $order);
    Mage::register('current_order', $order);
    return $order;
}
```

In order to use `Mage::registry('current_order')` it must first be set (`Mage::register('current_order', $order);`) some where , else you going to get a  Fatal error

Comment: thank, i registered collections. Now it is showing error Fatal error: Call to a member function setCollectionsProducts() on a non-object in CollectionsController.php also i am not finding any method with name setCollectionsProducts

Comment: I think i am unable to access object of layout block in function productsAction() in controller. Error  found for code $this->getLayout()->getBlock('collections.edit.tab.product') Here it returns Boolean false.

Comment: In order to keep this site clean, can you just create a new question and add code from your controller, layout.xml and config