# Magento admin add grid under a tab in custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, custom, grid-serlization

I want custom grid in tab

I have created a custom module in the admin panel and now want to create a grid to show, filter, etc the data under a tab  from a custom table. As like below screen

[image]

Right Now My tab comes like as bellow screen

[image]

I have added a Tab in Tab.php file

```
class Bluehorse_Warehouse_Block_Adminhtml_Warehouse_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs
{
        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->setId('warehouse_tabs');
                $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
                $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('warehouse')->__('Warehouse '));
        }
        protected function _beforeToHtml()
        {
                $this->addTab('warehouse', array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('warehouse')->__('Warehouse Information'),
                    'title' => Mage::helper('warehouse')->__('Warehouse Information'),
                    'content' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('warehouse/adminhtml_warehouse_edit_tab_form')->toHtml(),
                ));
                $this->addTab('zipcoe', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('warehouse')->__('Associated Zip Code'),
                    'title'     => Mage::helper('warehouse')->__('Associated Zip Code'),
                    'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/pincodes', array('_current' => true)),
                    'class'     => 'ajax',
                ));


                return parent::_beforeToHtml();
        }

}
```

Added a function

```
class Bluehorse_Warehouse_Adminhtml_WarehouseController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function pincodesAction () {
    //      

    }

  ................
```

There are my two tables one is

```
    +--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | firstname    | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
    | lastname     | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
    | phone        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
    | email        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
    | username     | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
    | password     | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
    | name         | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
    | zone         | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
    | zipcode      | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
    | address      | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | status       | smallint(6)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
    | created_time | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | update_time  | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    +--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Second is

```
    +---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | wid           | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | zipcode       | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | is_primary    | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
    | delivery_time | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | status        | smallint(6)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
    | position      | smallint(6)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
    | created_at    | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | updated_at    | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    +---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to showing a grid under my blank tab. 
How can do it? Can you help me.

I also take help from

[How to create the Product Grid Serializer Block In Custom module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13305/how-to-create-the-product-grid-serializer-block-in-custom-module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add below code in action

```
class Bluehorse_Warehouse_Adminhtml_WarehouseController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function pincodesAction () {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('edit.tab.pincodes');        
        $this->renderLayout();   

    }
}
```

Crete a grid file as below

```
class Bluehorse_Warehouse_Block_Adminhtml_Edit_Tab_Pincodes extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('pincodeGrid');
        $this->setUseAjax(true); // Using ajax grid is important
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');             
    }

    protected function _getStore()
    {
        $storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        return Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('Your-Model-Name')->getCollection();

        $this->setCollection($collection);

         parent::_prepareCollection();
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

        //add column here

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

}
```

Add below code to admin layout update file of your module

```
<adminhtml_warehouse_pincodes>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
            <block type="warehouse/adminhtml_edit_tab_pincodes" name="edit.tab.pincodes"/>
        </block>
    </adminhtml_warehouse_pincodes>
```

Comment: Nothing is coming in grid tab. Can you check it??

Comment: You need to do some modification as per your model name, layout block name.