# How to add product grid in custom module tab

Tags: magento-1.9, module, product-grid

I want to add product grid in custom module tab in Magento 1.9.x..

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Hello @Marius, Can you please ask me how can i archive this.

Comment: did you check the answer on the question linked to this one?

Comment: Yes,but everytime i get 500 Internal server error when i click on tab.

Comment: Debug it. you have the code. I don't

Comment: ok, please explain me of this line in controller:
$this->_initEntity(); 
because when i click on tab then first controller action call and first line this, and also i check code of up-selles product tab in product edit is same line there and i comment above line in core module then it's getting 500 Internal server error so can you please explain me why this happening. Thanx @Marius

Comment: Sorry. I don't know how your code is built. The `_initEntity` method should check the GET param for the id of the entity you are editing and load it from the db along with the associated products.

Comment: So can i create this action in  my controller??because it's not define in this post. :
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13305/how-to-create-the-product-grid-serializer-block-in-custom-module