# Fatal error: Call to a member function Fatal error: Call to a member function setRecipeProducts()

Tags: magento-1.9, module, blocks, magento-1, admin-controller

I am getting the error in my custom admin module -

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setRecipeProducts() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample\app\code\local\Sigmasolve\Recipe\controllers\Adminhtml\RecipeController.php on line 155

`Sigmasolve_Recipe` is my custom module name and here is the controller file:

```
public function _initRecipe()
{
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_title($this->__('Product Grid'))
        ->renderLayout();
}
public function productsAction()
{
    $this->_initRecipe(); //if you don't have such a method then replace it with something that will get you the entity you are editing.
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('recipe.edit.tab.product')
        ->setRecipeProducts($this->getRequest()->getPost('recipe_products', null));
    $this->renderLayout();
}
public function productsgridAction()
{
    $this->_initRecipe();
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('recipe.edit.tab.product')
        ->setRecipeProducts($this->getRequest()->getPost('recipe_products', null));
    $this->renderLayout();
}


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sigmasolve_Recipe>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Sigmasolve_Recipe>
    </modules>
   <!--  <frontend>
        <routers>
            <recipe>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Sigmasolve_Recipe</module>
                    <frontName>recipe</frontName>
                </args>
            </recipe>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <recipe>
                    <file>recipe.xml</file>
                </recipe>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend> -->
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <recipe>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Sigmasolve_Recipe</module>
                    <frontName>recipe</frontName>
                </args>
            </recipe>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <recipe module="recipe">
                <title>Recipe</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>                
                <children>
                    <items module="recipe">
                        <title>Manage Recipe</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>recipe/adminhtml_recipe</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </recipe>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <recipe>
                            <title>Recipe Module</title>
                            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        </recipe>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>    
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <recipe>
                    <file>recipe.xml</file>
                </recipe>
            </updates>

        </layout>
    </adminhtml>    
    <global>
        <models>
            <recipe>
                <class>Sigmasolve_Recipe_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>recipe_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </recipe>
            <recipe_mysql4>
                <class>Sigmasolve_Recipe_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <recipe>
                        <table>recipe</table>
                    </recipe>
                    <recipe_product>
                        <table>recipe_product</table>
                    </recipe_product>
                </entities>
            </recipe_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <recipe_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Sigmasolve_Recipe</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </recipe_setup>
            <recipe_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>


            </recipe_write>
            <recipe_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </recipe_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <recipe>
                <class>Sigmasolve_Recipe_Block</class>
            </recipe>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <recipe>
                <class>Sigmasolve_Recipe_Helper</class>
            </recipe>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have in the layout file corresponding to your module this

```
<recipe_adminhtml_recipe_products>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="recipe/adminhtml_recipe_edit_tab_product" name="recipe.edit.tab.product"/>
        <block type="adminhtml/widget_grid_serializer" name="product_grid_serializer">
            <reference name="product_grid_serializer">
                <action method="initSerializerBlock">
                    <grid_block_name>recipe.edit.tab.product</grid_block_name>
                    <data_callback>getSelectedProducts</data_callback>
                    <hidden_input_name>products</hidden_input_name>
                    <reload_param_name>recipe_products</reload_param_name>
                </action>
                <action method="addColumnInputName">
                    <input_name>position</input_name>
                </action>
            </reference>
        </block>
    </block>
</recipe_adminhtml_recipe_products>
<recipe_adminhtml_recipe_productsgrid>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="recipe/adminhtml_recipe_edit_tab_product" name="recipe.edit.tab.product"/>
</block>
</recipe_adminhtml_recipe_productsgrid>
```

Keep in mind that the layout handles `adminhtml_sigmasolve_recipe_products` and `adminhtml_sigmasolve_recipe_productsgrid` might be different depending on the url key your module has.
Also the block alias might be different. Instead of `sigmasolve_recipe` in `sigmasolve_recipe/adminhtml_recipe_edit_tab_product` you might need to put the tag name from under the `<blocks>` tag from your config.xml file.
But I see you followed [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/13309/146) to create your many to many relation with the products, so chances are you are using the same notation as I did above. If, indeed, you followed that answer, make sure you did not miss a file and that you cleared the cache.

Comment: yes @Marius you are right i am followed that answer. I put layout file in  "C:\xampp\htdocs\sample\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout"   so is this right or not?

Comment: yep, it's right

Comment: so i am try your answer but still get same error can you please help me out of this problem

Comment: please add to your question the `config.xml` file of your module.

Comment: i added config.xml file in my question..

Comment: @H_Parekh. I've edited the answer. You need to modify your layout handle names also. Give this a try and let me know how it turns out.

Comment: it gives same error

Comment: One last thing...what's the url of your admin page you are trying to access? Is it `[admin_key]/recipe/edit` or `recipe/adminhtml_recipe/edit`?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/sample/index.php/recipe/adminhtml_recipe/edit/key/951a1f44ed1bc9e37dd8428630339d40/

Comment: yes this is  one : recipe/adminhtml_recipe/edit

Comment: It seams right. I have no other ideas. It should work, but I guess I'm missing something. Just make sure all the blocks are there

Comment: In your entity model add these methods and a member variable that will process the product relation:  I am put that code in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample\app\code\local\Sigmasolve\Recipe\Model\Mysql4   Is it right?  or i need to add code in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample\app\code\local\Sigmasolve\Recipe\Model here

Comment: it should work, but that's not the problem in your case

Comment: ok thanks a lot Marius .. I think it's my bad luck..

Comment: `$this->addTab('products', array(
  'label' => Mage::helper('recipe')->__('Associated products'),
  //'url'   => $this->getUrl('*/*/products', array('_current' => true)),
  'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('recipe/adminhtml_recipe_edit_tab_product')->toHtml(),
  //'class'    => 'ajax'
 ));`   I wrote this in Tabs.php file And Get `Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample\app\code\local\Sigmasolve\Recipe\Block\Adminhtml\Recipe\Edit\Tab\Product.php on line 10` this error...

Comment: I think now you can help me ..

Comment: Uncomment the class = ajax line and the url = ... line and temove the content =.... line

Comment: if i uncomment url and ajax line also remove content line than it gives same error dude

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the following code:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('recipe.edit.tab.product')
```

does not return an existing block.

You need to **check your layout and the way this block is supposed to be added to your layout and fix it** in order for your code to work. It could be as simple as a typo.

Comment: `<block type="recipe/adminhtml_recipe_edit_tab_product" name="recipe.edit.tab.product"/>
        <block type="adminhtml/widget_grid_serializer" name="product_grid_serializer">`

Comment: @H_Parekh yes ok but in which layout handle is that added ?